# OOP Open/Closed principal in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Often heard about the Open/Closed principal that says a class should be Open for extension and Closed for modification.
Sounds great at the abstract level.

But is there any real-world use-cased example applied in the Ruby OOP land?

Answer (score 6):

Ruby classes are all open. There is no closed class.

Example:

```
class String
  def foo
    puts "bar"
  end
end

'anything'.foo

#bar
```

Comment: Well this principle is not a core definition for OOP, and it has been redefined according to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle

Comment: This isn't what the question is asking. 'closed' in the context of the open/closed principle doesn't mean that the class can't be 'opened' at runtime to add new functionality (what Rubyists usually refer to as 'monkey-patching'.) It means that when *designing your classes and APIs* you should try to do so in a way that minimises the chances of needing to change the class's existing functionality (as opposed to adding entirely new functionality) if the requirements change.

Answer (score 3):

Open/Closed Principle does apply well to Ruby.

Definition says.. you classes / objects should be open for extension but closed for modification. What does it mean?

It means that you should not go and modify the class to add new behaviour. You should achieve that either using inheritance or composition.

E.g.

```
class Modem
  HAYES = 1
  COURRIER = 2
  ERNIE = 3
end


class Hayes
  attr_reader :modem_type

  def initialize
    @modem_type = Modem::HAYES
  end
end

class Courrier
  attr_reader :modem_type

  def initialize
    @modem_type = Modem::COURRIER
  end
end

class Ernie
  attr_reader :modem_type

  def initialize
    @modem_type = Modem::ERNIE
  end
end



class ModemLogOn

  def log_on(modem, phone_number, username, password)
    if (modem.modem_type == Modem::HAYES)
      dial_hayes(modem, phone_number, username, password)
    elsif (modem.modem_type == Modem::COURRIER)
      dial_courrier(modem, phone_number, username, password)
    elsif (modem.modem_type == Modem::ERNIE)
      dial_ernie(modem, phone_number, username, password)
    end
  end

  def dial_hayes(modem, phone_number, username, password)
    puts modem.modem_type
    # implmentation
  end


  def dial_courrier(modem, phone_number, username, password)
    puts modem.modem_type
    # implmentation
  end

  def dial_ernie(modem, phone_number, username, password)
    puts modem.modem_type
    # implementation
  end
end
```

To support a new type of modem.. you have to go and modify the class.

Using inheritance . you can abstract out modem functionality. And

```
# Abstration
class Modem

  def dial
  end

  def send
  end

  def receive
  end

  def hangup
  end

end

class Hayes < Modem
  # Implements methods
end


class Courrier < Modem
  # Implements methods
end

class Ernie < Modem
  # Implements methods
end


class ModelLogON

  def log_on(modem, phone_number, username, password)
    modem.dial(phone_number, username, password)
  end

end
```

Now to support new type of modem.. you don't have to go and modify source code. You can add new code to add new type of modem.

This is how open/closed principle is achieved using inheritance. The principle can be achieved using many other techniques.